# How to read .img file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I'm developing a Windows Forms application where one of the things i need to do is, extract the image from .img file. I'm being able to read the normal jpg and png files, but not .img file.

I could not find much information on internet regarding this. I did find some code on msdn and i tried to get it to work. Below is the code and exception that is being thrown.

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FilePath.Text);
 FileStream f1 = new FileStream(FilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, 
 FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
 byte[] BytesOfPic = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(file.Length)];
 f1.Read(BytesOfPic, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.Length));

 MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
 mStream.Write(BytesOfPic, 0, Convert.ToInt32(BytesOfPic.Length));
 Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
 mStream.Dispose();

 // ImageBox is name of a PictureBox
 ImageBox.image = bm;   // this line is throwing the error
```

Exception caught

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>      at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream, Boolean useIcm)
>      at A02_Stegnography.Form1.ReadImgFile() in C:\Users\tiwar\Desktop\A02-Stegnography\A02-Stegnography\Form1.cs:line 65

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I hope i have provided enough information but if i haven't please let me know.

Comment: `img` is not an image file that u can open with memorystream

Comment: Yes, that's why i opened it with filestream, read it in byte array, then used MemoryStream to write it to bitmap.

Comment: ,oops,didn't see tht !

Comment: That error means your stream is null

Comment: Could you please give a little hint on how do i solve that?

Comment: What kind of image is the img file? System.Drawing.Bitmap only supports [certain file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-bitmaps#graphics-file-formats)

Comment: There are multiple .img files, some of them are jpg format and some are png.

Comment: I thought .img was for disk images?

Comment: Oh my bad. .img is a disk image. I thought John was asking about the extension of images before they were put into .img files.

Comment: You obviously can't open a disk image as picture... it's a file archive, not a graphics format.

Comment: Hi Nyerguds, i'm not opening it as a picture. I'm opening it with filestream, and using memory stream to write it to bitmap, which is evident from code i've posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FilePath.Text);
FileStream f1 = new FileStream(FilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
byte[] BytesOfPic = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(file.Length)];
f1.Read(BytesOfPic, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.Length));

using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    mStream.Write(BytesOfPic, 0, BytesOfPic.Length);
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);

    // ImageBox is name of a PictureBox
    ImageBox.image = bm;
}
```

You can try my solution for problem

Comment: Hi Chaunv, i tried your solution but still getting the same error. By the way, i just opened the .img file using a software, and turns out there are two .jpg images in it, not one. I don't know if it matters, but just wanted to let you know.

Comment: If your .img file contain 2 files .jpg then process occur error, because we load 1 image into 1 Picturebox. You need get 2 file .jpg and load into 2 Picturebox.

Comment: I'll see if i can find some solution, if i don't i'll probably use 7-zip to get the images externally. Will also accept your answer.